# Is there a better way to do this WHERE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My SQL is a little rusty and was just curious if there is a better way to do this WHERE clause? Assuming that there is a way, which I'm sure there is. It's runs pretty quick as it is, but I just don't like it and would like to know if it can be improved upon.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.firstname              ,
            p.middlename             ,
            p.lastname               ,
            p.gender                 ,
            p.dob                    ,
            p.id      AS patientid   ,
            pr.id     AS practiceid  ,
            pr.[name] AS practicename,
            pr.parentaco             ,
            pp.encounterdate
FROM            ((aco.patients_practices patients_practices
            LEFT OUTER JOIN aco.patients p
            ON              (
                             patients_practices.patientid = p.id
                            )
            )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN aco.practices pr
            ON              (
                             patients_practices.practiceid = pr.id
                            )
            )
            INNER JOIN aco.patientpreferences pp
            ON              (
                             pp.patientid = p.id
                            )
WHERE           (
                            pr.parentaco =
                            (SELECT parentaco
                            FROM    aco.practices
                            WHERE   master_companyid = 763
                            )
            OR              pr.id =
                            (SELECT parentaco
                            FROM    aco.practices
                            WHERE   master_companyid = 763
                            )
            )
AND             pp.encounterdate IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Does `master_companyid` have a unique constraint?

Comment: no since it can have many children. It's the FK from Master_Company table.

Comment: Your references to `pr` in the `WHERE` clause effectively converts the `LEFT OUTER` joins to `INNER` joins.  The trailing `INNER` join doesn't help that, either.

Comment: @HABO How would you write it?

Comment: You are joining to aco.patients_practices as alias patients_practices and as alias pp both the same join condition but one join is outer and one is an inner.

Comment: @Blam pp is alias for patientpreferences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could fetch the value from you sub-query first and put it in variable.

```
DECLARE @P INT

SELECT @P = parentaco
FROM aco.practices
WHERE master_companyid = 763
```

Use the variable in the query

```
WHERE (pr.parentaco = @P or pr.id = @P) AND
      pp.encounterdate IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s are effectively converted to `INNER JOIN`s due to the manner in which they are referenced in the `WHERE` clause.  I think you'll find that this is logically equivalent:

```
select distinct p.firstname, p.middlename, p.lastname,
  p.gender, p.dob, p.id as patientid,
  pr.id as practiceid, pr.[name] as practicename, pr.parentaco,
  pp.encounterdate
  from aco.patients_practices as patients_practices inner join
    aco.patients as p on p.id = patients_practices.patientid inner join
    aco.practices as pr on pr.id = patients_practices.practiceid inner join
    aco.patientpreferences as pp on pp.patientid = p.id
  where pp.encounterdate is not null and
    ( pr.parentaco = ( select parentaco from aco.practices where master_companyid = 763 ) or
    pr.id = ( select parentaco from aco.practices where master_companyid = 763 ) )
```

Regarding the duplicate subquery in the `WHERE` clause: the query optimizer should recognize the duplication and handle it accordingly.  You can confirm that by examining the execution plan.  Using Mikael Eriksson's advice to capture the `parentaco` in a variable should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the same condition twice in the where condition? Did you mean to use a different ID the second time?

Why not just join against the practices table and then just do a where condition there, without the subselect?

Comment: It's not exactly the same. One is looking at the parentaco the other id. parentaco is a self-referencing to id for parent child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be 100% but hopefully will guide get you going in the correct condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.firstname          ,
            p.middlename             ,
            p.lastname               ,
            p.gender                 ,
            p.dob                    ,
            p.id      AS patientid   ,
            pr.id     AS practiceid  ,
            pr.[name] AS practicename,
            pr.parentaco             ,
            pp.encounterdate
FROM        aco.patients_practices pp
            LEFT OUTER JOIN aco.patients p
              ON  pp.patientid = p.id  
            LEFT OUTER JOIN aco.practices pr
              ON  pp.practiceid = pr.id
              AND ( pr.parentaco = pp.parentco or pr.id = pp.parentco )
WHERE    pp.encounterdate IS NOT NULL
         AND pp.master_companyid = 763
```